# Typical Sequence Definition

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I am realities new in Information Theoty and probability but I have a question about the Typical Sequence Definition.
So I came across this:

[image]

What does it actuallly mean by "sequences (x1,x2...)".

Does it mean any combination of x_i for    $$x_i \epsilon\ X_i\\$$
forms a sequence (x1,x2....)?

Thank you

Comment: "Sequence" in this context means the same thing as it does normally in mathematics: an ordered list of elements from a set. Here the sequence is finite, so the sequence is an ordered list of $n$ elements from the set $\mathcal{X}$. In more mathematical terms, a sequence of $n$ elements from $\mathcal{X}$ is a function from the subset of positive integers $\{1, \ldots, n \}$ to $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: Note that $X_i$ is a random variable, not a set, so it does not have elements. The set (or alphabet) is written as a chi, i.e. $\chi$, which in MathJax is typed as ```$\chi$```.

Comment: I see what you mean, but my main problem is how to dinstinguish $\ x$, $\ X$ and $\chi$. What I understand, $\chi$ is the alphabet, $\ x$ can be any value in the alphabet and $\ X$ is a random variable which maps all the values of $\ x$ to an outcome, right? Also what is the difference of saying $x_i \epsilon\chi$  and $X_i \epsilon\chi$?? Also is $\CHI\ and $\chis$ different?

Comment: Mostly correct. In probability theory, a capital letter (in this case $X$) is typically used for a random variable, which is a function from the sample space of a probability space to a measurable space (in this case $\chi$). The same letter, but in lower case (in this case $x$) represents "realizations", which are elements of the measurable space. For example, if the experiment that generates the sequence is flipping a coin $n$ times, then the sample space is $\{ \mathrm{heads}, \mathrm{tails} \}$, and $\chi$ may be $\{0,1\}$, where $X$ maps $\mathrm{heads}$ to $1$ and $\mathrm{tails}$ to 0.

Comment: Each realization will be an element of the measurable space, so $x_i \in \chi$, but $X_i$ is a random variable, not a set, so $X_i$ does not have elements.

Comment: I should clarify that above, when I said "flipping a coin $n$ times", the outcome of each flip is $x_i \in \chi$, a realization of $X_i$, but the outcome of the $n$ ordered flips is $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \chi^n$, a realization of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, which is called a random vector.

Comment: I see beacause this makes sense, but I saw another definitions $\(X1,…,Xn)\epsilon\chin_n$ and it got me confused. Thank you!

Comment: More specificaly in data compression, for the symbos (random variables) $X_1,X_2...$ can I say that $X_1,X_2...\epsilon \chi$ ? Where $\chi$ is the alphabet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the conventions in data compression, but in probability theory in general it is customary to abuse notation by dropping the argument of the function, as in writing $P(X \in S)$ instead of $P(X(\omega) \in S)$. For example, writing $P(X<3)$, to mean $P(X(\omega) < 3)$. Here, the same symbol is being used to name the function and the output of that function. It's as if we have a function $f(t)$ and we asked for what values of $t$ is $f<3$.